# how to create a script for outlook?

Tags: email, scripting, outlook, email-attachments

I need a script which automatically create emails saved in my draft folder with a certain message to for each email and a certain address (one or more) so I can quickly just edit & send those messages to my clients.
how can I do that? how to even begin - with what language?

And also - is it possible to add a specific attachment?

Answer (score 1):

GO under Developer, there is a Visual Basic Button. He opens a windows where you can program in VBA.